# Only allow remote desktop connection in Linux

Tags: linux, boot, remote-desktop

Is there a way to only allow remote desktop connections in Linux? So as soon as they boot, they are prompted to a remote desktop session?  If this is readily supported only on specific distros, that's fine.

Comment: Any Linux running in a computer with no display attached? Or your question requires a bit more context?

Comment: +1, You don't need anything special for "only remote desktop". Just install any Linux with VNC Server, make VNC server autostart at boot, set very strong password for local user, and normal password for VNC. Done. Or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to achieve a remote desktop kiosk

As far as I know such a distro doesn't exist, but it should be achievable with most distros [with some hacking and configuration](https://itekblog.com/tiny-core-linux-remote-desktop-kiosk/).